# Flutter Pub Get command failed

Tags: flutter, dart, text-to-speech

I'm getting this error message on running the command : `flutter pub get`

```
Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8', path = 'C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_tts-1.2.6\pubspec.yaml'
Running "flutter pub get" in dhiyo-app...                               
pub get failed (66; Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8', path = 'C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_tts-1.2.6\pubspec.yaml')
```

Comment: Is your `minSdkVersion` set to  `21` or higher?

Comment: Could you try with some older version of `flutter_tts` like v1.2.3

Comment: Check in your `pubspec.yaml` you have used `flutter_tts: ^1.2.6` with proper indentation?

Comment: Well I ran flutter pub cache repair and it solved the issue.

Comment: Good. You can add a self answer and mark it as accepted so that it helps others with same issue.